# Cassandra: bigger replication factor = faster reads?

Tags: cassandra

Does increasing replication factor on a cluster also increase the read speed?

I understand that when replication factor is 1, and there's 6 nodes and the tokens are distributed equally - then it's only 16,66% chance that given node has the data, if it does not have it, it asks the node responsible and that takes extra time.

I guess that with replication factor set to 6, each node has the full dataset and can fetch data immediately without asking other nodes (we're using read consistency=1). So increasing replication factor should increase reading speed. Is this correct?

Our app has relatively few writes but more than 10k get() operations per second. We have 6 nodes in the cluster and we need all read operations to be extremely fast, that's why we're looking for a way to improve cassandra's read performance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's correct, as long as you're using ConsistencyLevel.ONE.

Comment: Can you provide some reference for this. It seems to contradict my intuition. As far as I know, reads are sent to *all* replicas, no matter what consistency level is used.

Comment: @user1202136 I realize this is an old post, but just to avoid confusion for anyone reading this... Write and read consistency is tune-able in Cassandra. Here's a whole section on read consistency http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cassandra/2.0/cassandra/dml/dmlClientRequestsRead.html

Answer (score 4):

I actually run the ycsb benchmarks- 100% write and 100% Read- to test this.
Increasing the replication factor seems to be causing slower reads while the consistency level is kept at one.

In an 8 node cluster here are the numbers I am getting:

16 million read operations-ycsb workload C

rep.factor        _          readtime(min)

1                _          10.8840833333333

2                _          11.1243666666667

4                _          17.4050333333333

For greater sizes the jump is even bigger.

Can anyone explain why?

Comment: If I understood Cassandra correctly, reads and writes go to *all* replicas, no matter what the consistency level is. Therefore, increasing replication factor should increase the load on nodes. Actually, I am surprised that doubling the replication factor does not double the readtime.

Comment: @user1202136 the reads and writes will go to all replicas only if the respective consistencies are set to the number of replicas i.e. the replication factor. By default it will only read from a single replica.

Comment: @adarshhegde You are right. I re-read the documentation and other replicas are only contacted as part of read repair with a lower probability, by default 0.1. So, on average, more replicas are part of the read than the consistency level, but, on average, not all of them are contacted. http://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/1.2/cassandra/architecture/architectureClientRequestsRead_c.html